# Global Error handling with Observable.toPromise()

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

Hi i am using angular 5 and i am writing a global handler for the same which looks like following.

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorsHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  constructor(
    private injector: Injector,
  ) { }


  handleError(error: Error | HttpErrorResponse) {
    const router = this.injector.get(Router);
    const zone = this.injector.get(NgZone);
    console.log('Here')
    console.log(error)

    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {

      // Client Error Happend
      zone.run(() => router.navigate(['/error'], { queryParams: { error: JSON.stringify(error) } }))

    } else {
      // Log the error anyway
      router.navigate(['/error'], { queryParams: { error: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Failed' }) } });
    }
  }
}
```

Everything works fine in Observable world ie if i do a failed http call like following

```
fireServerError() {
    this.httpService
            .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/1')
            .subscribe(data => console.log('Data: ', data));
  }
```

and if the server call fails i get an error object properly as shown in the console image

[image]

But instead of that if i change it to a promise using toPromise(), like following

```
fireServerError() {
    this.httpService
            .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/1')
            .toPromise();
  }
```

i get the following string stack trace instead of error Object itself

[image]

What am i doing wrong. How to throw/get the error object in case of unhandled promise rejections. Please help. I am stuck;

Please find the stackblitz link [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/error-handling-in-angular-step1-vqsgan?file=app%2Ffeatures%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts)

Comment: did you try something like the following: `fireServerError() {
    this.httpService.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/1').toPromise().catch(err => console.error(err));
}`

Comment: Yes, but i donot want to swallow the error in the catch block but rethrow it again so that global error handler will handle it. I have attached the stackblitz link to realise the problem.

Comment: if inside the catch you do return a new resolved promise with the error `Promise.resolve(err)`?

Comment: Again it gets swallowed na unless you throw it again so that global handler can handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Once you use `.toPromise()`, you are essentially putting the behavior into a different execution context (read [ECMAScript 10.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4)), which means that errors must be handled in/around the new execution context rather than having them bubble up in Angular like you are expecting.

I can't say I entirely follow your example code (is `fireServerError` always supposed to throw an error via an HTTP call?), but it seems like you want to try to execute promises without local error handling, but rather to have any error from a promise bubble up to the angular error handling. I'm not sure I'd recommend that, I believe it's best-practice to handle promise errors locally (i.e. using `Promise.prototype.catch` or a `try/await/catch block` when you create the promise).

That being said, error handling is of course a complicated topic and if you are dead set on just handling all errors at the global level then you can try using a global window event handler to catch all unhandled [promise rejections](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unhandledrejection_event) and handle them there:

```
window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", event => {
  event.preventDefault(); // prevent the default promise rejection behavior
  console.error(event); // do whatever you want with the error
}, false);
```

The [MDN guide on promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) may also help clear some things up, hope that helps!